# Qual é a diferença entre dado e informação?

Tags: terminologia

Segundo esta definição de **Dado**:

> Dados são um conjunto de informações (quantitativas, qualitativas,
> categóricas ou indefinidas) podendo ser organizadas ou não.
>
> [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dados).

Seguindo esta linha eu posso assumir que **dado(s)** e **informação** são as mesmas coisas. Entretanto, na faculdade meu professor disse que **dado** não é **informação** quando o mesmo não é tratado ou quando ele não possui algum significado.

Por exemplo, este é um dado `29` e `M` também é um dado, porem, eu não sei o que esses dados representam, como eles poderiam ser considerados informação. E é neste ponto que surgi minha dúvida que vem logo abaixo.

---

## Dúvida

Eu gostaria de saber qual é a diferença entre **dado** e **informação** e o que faz com que **dado(s)** se torne **informação**?

Comment: Sua pegunta não seria informação x conhecimento?

Comment: @GOKUSSJ4 não, apenas informação e dados, eu até cheguei a pensar nisso, porque acho que conhecimento é mais amplo, e quero focar no contexto da Computação ;).

Comment: Ah bom entendi.

Comment: Eu acho a sua pergunta bacana, mas ela me parece meio ampla. Por exemplo, você incluiu a tag [tag:estrutura-de-dados] nela, e nesse contexto (de programação de uma estrutura de dados) pode ser que o que o seu professor falou faça sentido. Mas em outro escopo isso não é necessariamente verdade. Não vou votar pra fechar, entretanto, porque pode ser que eu esteja enganado e exista uma resposta canônica.

Comment: @LuizVieira eu coloquei a tag [estrutura-de-dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/estrutura-de-dados/info) porque é a parte em que mais manipula os dados em sua forma mais bruta, poderia ser banco de dados mas acho q não faria muito sentido. O objetivo da pergunta e trazer uma resposta que esclarece a diferença entre dado e informação já que toda Tecnologia da Informação, Computação e Desenvolvimento de Software tem como base Dados e Informação e qualquer outro Sistema da Informação faz parte deste conceito.

Comment: Justamente. Em cada uma dessas áreas que você citou a distinção entre dado e informação pode não ser a mesma. Eu só citei a tag como um exemplo em que eu acho que o que o seu professor disse talvez faça sentido. Mas não é o caso em Teoria da Informação, por exemplo.

Comment: @LuizVieira acho que a teoria da informação aborda esta questão :), mas achei interessante forcar em duas questão diferença entre informação e dado, e como um dado se torna informação, a resposta para essas duas questões seria tão ampla assim?

Comment: Se a pergunta for entender exemplos como esses do `29` e do `M`, acho que a resposta do rray basta. É isso? Parece ser, considerando que você parte do princípio de que *dado* é anterior a *informação*. Mas como disse o @LuizVieira isso é uma das definições possíveis, dentro de um campo restrito. Difícil que haja uma definição universal. A própria citação da wikipedia não ajuda muito, parece ser derivada do verbete em inglês – que não cita nenhuma fonte primárias, só umas secundárias meio mais-ou-menos. Tudo isso pra dizer que gostei da pergunta, mas não sei até onde dá pra responder :)

Comment: Eu não acho que a Teoria da Informação aborda isso. Realmente não lembro de ter essa distinção, era tudo "informação". Mas se você achar uma fonte que diga o contrário, talvez seja material para uma resposta da sua própria parte. :)

Comment: @DenerCarvalho [Esse artigo](http://www.business2community.com/strategy/difference-data-information-0967136#ZvB6RUV6FpYrJe6g.97) (em *inglês*) e esse [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIKW_Pyramid) da Wikipedia talvez ajude a esclarecer um pouco.

Comment: @zekk vou dar uma olhada obrigado

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Dado

Acredito que o conceito de dados tem uma definição relativamente precisa, sendo usado com a mesma interpretação em diversas áreas. Na computação existem por exemplo os termos estrutura de dados, banco de dados e mineração de dados, nas telecomunicações transmissão de dados, pacote de dados, dados móveis, já a estatística tem o conceito de dado estatístico e várias outras áreas também utilizam esse termo.

Todas essas áreas utilizam este termo com a definição que você apresentou da Wikipédia. É claro que existem pequenas diferenças, como exemplo em alguns livros de telecomunicações o termo dado é utilizado como sinônimo de informação digital, contrapondo transmissão de dados e transmissão de voz, onde a voz não é considerada dado por se tratar de um sinal analógico, ou seja, o dado teria que ser digital. Mas fora essas sutilezas o conceito de dado é o mesmo na maioria dos casos.

### Informação

Já o termo informação, certamente não tem uma definição precisa. O próprio Shannon, considerado pai da teoria da informação escreveu o seguinte ao tentar definir informação:

> The word “information” has been given different meanings by various writers in the general field of information theory. It is likely that at least a number of these will prove sufficiently useful in certain applications to deserve further study and permanent recognition. It is hardly to be expected that a single concept of information would satisfactorily account for the numerous possible applications of this general field.

Tradução:

> Para a palavra "informação" foi dado diferentes significados por vários escritores no campo geral da teoria da informação. É provável que pelo menos um certo número destas abordagens seja suficientemente útil em certas aplicações tal que mereça reconhecimento permanente. Dificilmente é de se esperar que um único conceito de informação iria explicar satisfatoriamente suas inúmeras aplicações possíveis.

Como exemplo desta diferença de significados, um grande número de estudiosos defendem que o pensamento é particular do ser humano e um computador não pode pensar. Também existem vários pesquisadores que defendem que um computador pode ter a mesma forma de inteligência que um ser humano. Em certos contextos a informação é tratada como particular do ser humano, ou seja, se futuramente for descoberto que um computador realmente não pode pensar, ou realmente pode pensar isso mudaria o conceito de informação. Uma definição final de informação dependeria de questões que nós ainda não sabemos a reposta, e portanto ainda é um termo em desenvolvimento.

### Definição de informação

Para o contexto desta pergunta uma definição bem útil foi descrita por um filósofo italiano chamado Luciano Floridi que consiste na chamada definição geral da informação:

> The General Definition of Information (GDI):
>   σ is an instance of information, understood as semantic content, if and only if:
>
> 1. σ consists of one or more data;
> 2. the data in σ are well-formed;
> 3. the well-formed data in σ are meaningful.

Tradução

> A definição geral de informação (GDI):
>   σ é uma instância de informação, entendida como conteúdo semântico, se e somente se:
>
> 1. σ consiste em um ou mais dados;
> 2. os dados em σ são bem formados;
> 3. os dados bem formados em σ têm significado.

Nesta definição já fica bem claro a diferença entre dado e informação e ela se encaixa com o entendimento do seu professor. A informação não existe sem um ou mais dados, mas nem todo dado é informação. O que faz os dados se tornarem informação é o tratamento e o significado.

Mas significado é um conceito abstrato e ainda não compreendido em sua totalidade. Se em determinado contexto só um ser humano pode dar significado a um dado, então a informação só existe na cabeça de um ser humano. E isso pode variar de pessoa pra pessoa, se uma pessoa não entende números binários, um conjunto destes números não tem significado pra ela, já se outra pessoa entende, pra ela tem significado.

Esta é uma definição mais ampla, que é usada em diversas áreas e provavelmente a que o seu professor estava se referindo.

### Utilidade

Mas pensando bem, se você tem um programa que usa um dado, seu dado está ali e faz o que tem que fazer, qual a diferença se ele é informação ou não? Esta definição de que informação tem que ter significado não tem muita utilidade para a computação, pois é muito subjetiva.

Já a definição de Shannon é extremamente útil. Nela a informação pode ser medida, então existe a quantidade de informação. Os dados são medidos em bytes e a informação também! Portanto um arquivo pode ter 8KB de dados e 1KB de informação. Se este arquivo for compactado ele pode ficar por exemplo com 4KB de dados e os mesmos 1KB de informação. Como eu posso descompactar o arquivo e voltar para os 8KB originais nenhuma informação foi perdida!

Neste caso a informação não depende de ter significado ou de um observador.

Comment: Apesar de eu ter "positivado" todas as respostas =). A sua eu achei mais completa, pois ela entra no campo da filosofia, que na minha opinião, é a melhor forma para tentar explicar algo (como você mesmo citou)  muito abstrato.

Answer (score 22):

**Dado** é algo bruto, como o `29` ou o `M` da sua pergunta. Eles por si só não fazem sentido nenhum, não é possível tirar nenhum conclusão do que são, para o que servem ou de qual contexto pertencem.

**Informação**: é o dado mais contexto ou interpretação. Ou seja, tem um significado definido e serve para demonstrar alguma coisa. Por exemplo, o `M` pode ser a representação do sexo masculino, o `29` a idade ou talvez um dia do mês. Veja como o dado necessita de um contexto e interpretação para virar uma informação.

Comment: O segundo parágrafo ficou meio confuso.

Comment: @diegofm seria o começo? `Informação: é o dado mais contexto`?

Comment: Isso. Apesar que dar pra entender lendo o restante, esse começo ai ficou meio confuso.

Comment: Antes de mais nada, eu não discordo do que você falou. Mas, tem alguma fonte fidedigna? Pergunto porque isso não é necessariamente uma verdade absoluta. Posso estar enganado, mas pelo que me lembro, na [Teoria da Informação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoria_da_informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o) essa distinção não é tão certa. Uma tela cheia de ruído (canal não sintonizado na TV), por exemplo, tem a maior quantidade de **informação**, ainda que não exista padrão compreensível ali.

Comment: @LuizVieira não, o lugar menos ruim que achei foi na [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_computing), depois vou dar uma editada na resposta, com uma **informação** nova :D

Comment: Dei um tapa na "informação" da pergunta :D

Answer (score 7):

Reforçando o que já responderam,

Temos aqui a letra **A**. Essa letra é um dado. Não há um contexto claro sobre o que representa então é apenas um dado.

Agora temos aqui a letra **A** dentro de um contexto de [notas musicais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_note).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Representa a nota [La](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_(musical_note)).

Nesse contexto, passa a ser uma informação.

Num violão/guitarra, representa a quinta corda solta
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Também pode ser lida como no diagrama abaixo, representando o pressionar nas cordas 2, 3 e 4 no segundo traste.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguns podem achar isso fora de escopo, mas existe um objetivo aqui, que é o de elucidar o foco da questão.

Aqui nesses exemplos da nota musical temos um **dado** que representa **informações** diferentes.

## Podemos complicar? Sim, é claro que sim!

Agora vamos complicar mais as coisas. Ainda usando o exemplo da letra A, podemos também dizer que A é uma informação.

Aí você pensa, mas que merd@ vc está falando?

Veja, depende do contexto.

Para um computador, a letra A é uma informação composta pelos dados 01000001. Pois é assim que toda máquina enxerga as coisas, no formato binário.

Nesse contexto, `01000001` são os dados e `A` é a informação.

## Diferenças linguísticas e interpretações

Note que discussões como essa sobre o significado de dados e informação dependem também do idioma.

No idioma português normalmente costumamos fazer mal uso das palavras, empregando-as em locais que não deveriam ser usadas.

Exemplo:

**Idioma português**
(ambos fazem sentido)

Recebi os dados da notícia

Recebi as informações da notícia.

**Idioma japonês**

(não faz sentido usar dessa forma)

ニュースデータをお届け

(isso faz sentido)

ニュース情報をお届け

<sub>データ: dados</sub>

<sub>情報: informação</sub>

Aqui, dados representa algo abstrato, sem um significado.
Informação representa algo concreto. Algo que possui um conjunto de dados que compõem a informação.

No idioma português misturamos muito as coisas e acabamos criando duplo sentido, causando confusões como essa.

## Resumindo

O significado sobre o que é um **dado** e o que é uma **informação** depende do contexto e também do idioma.

Informação é um conjunto de dados, de conhecimentos, um produto, é comunicação.

Dado é algo abstrato e no idioma português contemporâneo pode ser interpretado como informação dentro de contextos específicos como os mencionados nos exemplos acima.

Comment: Pra mim, lá não é uma informação, mesmo no contexto de notas musicais. Quando a letra A representa a nota lá isso é uma codificação e não informação. Uma sequência de notas formando uma melodia é uma informação. A frase "A nota lá é a quinta corda do violão" contém informação, a informação te traz algo novo, neste caso uma associação entre lá e a quinta corda. Posso estar errado, mas acho que a nota lá é uma letra de um alfabeto musical e por isso não difere da letra A, o mesmo acontece com sua forma em acorde ou a forma binária, todos esses são dados e não informação.

Comment: como eu citei diversas vezes, tudo depende do contexto e há o fator do uso dos termos em cada idioma, no caso o portugues, também comentado na resposta. Se vc tirar do contexto fica estranho e leva para uma interpretação como essa que descreveu. Existe um contexto aí nisso tudo. Não foi a toa que escrevi tanta coisa para elucidar.  Evitei entrar muito nesse tema pois sairia muito do foco e escopo do site. Para um melhor entendimento é preciso estudar música.

Comment: Deixando mais claro, sobre o que comentou da nota musical, não está errado o que comentou desde que tenha um contexto específico. Mas observe bem o que eu quis colocar, especialmente na terceira imagem com as notas  do, re, mi, sol, la.  Dentro daquela tablatura, representam informação pois, dentro desse contexto, um músico enxerga o significado, há uma informação, é concreto. Enfim, talvez foi um exemplo complicado demais para elucidar, mas foi o mais conveniente que consegui criar no momento de responder justamente pensando na ambiguidade e diferenças de interpretação conforme o contexto.

Comment: Ok, interpretando desse jeito esta parte faz sentido. O que eu quis dizer é que o contexto é informação! Por isso existe a tão falada informação contextual. O lá sozinho não é informação, mas o conjunto lá + contexto é uma informação maior que o contexto sozinho. Pelo texto eu tinha entendido que o lá sozinho é uma informação se interpretado em um contexto, mas não tem como separar uma partícula de informação, isso seria um dado. Quando você falou que a letra A é uma informação composta pelos dados 01000001 a minha interpretação fez bastante sentido, mas realmente tem outro modo de enxergar

Answer (score 6):

## Dados

> "Dados" vem de uma palavra latina singular, dado, que originalmente
>   significava "algo dado." Seu uso no início remonta a 1600. Ao longo do
>   tempo "dados" tornou-se o plural de datum

Dados são fatos brutos, desorganizados que precisam ser processados. Os dados podem ser algo simples e aparentemente aleatória e inútil até que seja organizado. Os dados são percepcionados através dos sentidos e, uma vez integrados, acabam por gerar a informação necessária para produzir o conhecimento.

**Exemplo**:Resultado de testes de cada aluno numa classe são dados.

## Informação

> "Informação" é uma palavra antiga que remonta a 1300 e tem origens dos
>   Antigos Franceses e Médios Ingleses. Sempre se referiu ao "ato de informar",
>   geralmente no que diz respeito à educação, instrução ou outra
>   comunicação do conhecimento.

A informação é um conjunto organizado de dados, que constitui uma mensagem sobre um determinado fenômeno ou evento. A informação permite resolver problemas e tomar decisões, tendo em conta que o seu uso racional é a base do conhecimento. Quando os dados são processados, organizada, estruturada ou apresentado num determinado contexto de modo a torná-lo útil, que é chamado de informação.

**Exemplo**:A pontuação média de uma classe ou de toda a escola é a informação que pode ser derivada a partir dos dados apresentados.

Dê uma lida [aqui](http://conceito.de/informacao).

Comment: @GOKUSSJ4 Realmente **conhecimento** é algo mais completo. Acredito eu que o conhecimento é relacionado com experiência; prática de vida, que envolve todo um conjunto de informações, e por si só, muitos **dados**. Daí então vem outra coisa muito legal que também tem uma relação, que é a **sabedoria**.

Comment: goku, conhecimento é informação. ou também conjunto de informações...  resumindo bem grosseiramente, informações são dados absorvidos e conhecimento são informações absorvidas. Por isso achei injusto o negativo aqui e votei positivo çois o que ele descreveu de forma bastante clara e resumida, está de acordo com o que é descrito em dicionários e enciclopédias da lingua portuguesa

Comment: @DanielOmine, eu sei disso, só que o autor especificou nos cometário ( porque acho que conhecimento é mais amplo, e quero focar no contexto da Computação)

Comment: +1 .. Ao meu ver o @CleidimarViana falou sobre informação x dados. O fato de ter citado "conhecimento" só serviu para agregar com uma informação que as outras respostas não tinham.